# How to redirect user "back two pages" after login

Tags: 7, users, redirection

My users are only able to log in on the mysite.com/user page (I don't use any of the login blocks). How can I redirect those users to their location "two pages ago"? For example, they might visit the about us page, then click login (taking them to the /user page). After they complete their login, I would like for them to be redirected back to the about us page.

I currently have it set to redirect to the previous page after login, but that will always be the "user" page, which is not particularly useful in this instance.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Append

```
?destination=[PATH]
```

to your login link.

You can do this with the [Menu Token](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_token) Module

Comment: So it would look like this?  mysite.com/user?destination=[PATH]... Or do I need to add a path where it says "[PATH]" in your example? If the latter is true, then that will not work as that would create a single redirect destination and I need the redirect destination to be "two pages ago".

Comment: well you'd take the current url alias and apply that to the login link. I guess you'd have to also disable the automatic redirection to user page. You might try that. If that doesn't work you could try making use of a session variable.

Comment: also check this page https://www.drupal.org/node/683696

Answer (score 0):

If you have put the `user/login` in a menu you can you this theme function in your `template.php` file to override the links to add the `destination` parameter, here is a sample code.

```
function yourthemename_menu_link(array $variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $sub_menu = '';

  if ($element['#below']) {
    $sub_menu = drupal_render($element['#below']);
  }
  // Add destination query parameter for login, logout and register menus
  if (in_array($element['#href'], array('user/login', 'user/register'))) {
    $element['#localized_options']['query'] = array('destination' => current_path());
  }
  $output = l($element['#title'], $element['#href'], $element['#localized_options']);
  return '<li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $output . $sub_menu . "</li>\n";
}
```